# Cordova file transfer plugin "doesn't support this project's cordova-android version"

Tags: android, cordova, file-transfer

I'm having some issues when try to add file transfer plugin to my project, it shows me:

> Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.1.2, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0

And after that I can't build my Android app, just in case, I'm using Cordova 6.2.0 But I tried to use 6.5.0 but the same happens. How can I add properly this plugin?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running this command

```
ionic cordova platform update android
```